# unable to get data from web api using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, c#-3.0

```
 - 
<ArrayOftblEmp xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication6"> <tblEmp> <Age>21</Age> <Id>1</Id> <Name>Narasingh</Name> <Salary>15000.0000</Salary> </tblEmp> <tblEmp> <Age>22</Age> <Id>2</Id> <Name>johny</Name> <Salary>20000.0000</Salary> </tblEmp> <tblEmp> <Age>50</Age> <Id>3</Id> <Name>Patrik</Name> <Salary>300000.0000</Salary> </tblEmp> <tblEmp> <Age>45</Age> <Id>4</Id> <Name>Gudumba Shankar</Name> <Salary>250000.0000</Salary> </tblEmp> </ArrayOftblEmp>

var app = angular.module('crudapp', []);


app.controller('dbCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
$scope.test = 'hihi';

$scope.dataemp = function () {
    $scope.test2 = 'check';
    debugger;
    $http.get('http://localhost:1574/api/emp')
             .then(function (response) {
                 $scope.data = response.data;
             });
};
```

});

i couldn't bind it to html page. how can show in table this data using angularjs

Comment: getting data from web api , but i couldn't bind it to html page using angularjs

Answer (score 0):

i have a nice demo for that operation, here:
http://codepen.io/NateBen/pen/WopZje

notice the JS section, its a ES6, you can switch to vanilla JS, and notice this code:

```
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: root + '/users/'
}).then(function (response) {
  // handle success
  console.log(response);
  $scope.dataUsers = response.data;

}, function (response) {
  // handle error
  console.log(response);
});
```

$scope.dataUsers is your model you should bind to html, with a repeater.